# Google Analytics User ID view not tracking pageviews or events

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking, page-views

I've implemented user ID and it looks like it give the data correctly. I can see user ID and their sessions.
Anyway, what is not working properly is the ability to track pageviews and events. IN hte Real time, I can't see just visited page or event. If I open the other view containing all data, I can see both the pageview and event.

This is very strange, since the data is being sent. The same can be said about ecommerce data.

The user id view was created by GA when enabling user ID. No other changes, like filters, etc. were implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that each tag has to contain the user ID field.